# Does SSRS preview create phantom error messages?

Tags: visual-studio, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using Visual Studio 2017 to design a SSRS report.  Are some of the error messages one sees when they click on the Preview button actually meaningless?  For example, I get, "The tablix 'Tablix2' is invalid. The value for the DataSetName property is missing."  But when I look at the xml for the rdl file, I can not find any "Tablix2".

Report Properties are empty.   When I build, there are no errors or warnings

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio is probably showing you all the errors from the SOLUTION rather than just the one report. There should a drop down menu below the Error List window title bar with the different scope selections.

It defaults to **Entire Solution** but you can change it to **Current Document**.

[image]

The errors also don't disappear after you correct them (thx MS). You need to close and re-open VS to not see them.